# Can't start a ZNC service

Tags: centos, services, init.d

I try to start ZNC using the following command

```
service znc start
```

I get this error

```
Starting znc: /usr/bin/dirname: extra operand `2>&1.pid'
Try `/usr/bin/dirname --help' for more information.
                                                           [FAILED]
```

This is what the init.d script looks like

```
exec=/usr/bin/znc
prog=znc
config=/var/lib/znc
runas=znc

lockfile=/var/lock/subsys/$prog

start() {
[ -x $exec ] || exit 5
echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
# if not running, start it up here, usually something like "daemon $exec"
daemon --user $runas "$exec -d $config >/dev/null 2>&1"
# If you're reckless with your system, comment the line above and
# uncomment this one below... I just don't get it why
#daemon "$exec -r -d $config >/dev/null 2>&1"
retval=$?
echo
[ $retval -eq 0 ] && touch $lockfile
return $retval
}
```

Anyone know what would cause this.

I'm running centos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created a sample init script based on your question's code and determined that you need to change the one line by moving the double quote from the end to nearer the middle:

```
daemon --user $runas "$exec" -d $config >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The `daemon()` function in `/etc/init.d/functions` looks at the first non-argument parameter, strips back the program path to the basename and uses that to derive the PID lock file. By (wrongly) quoting the entire string, the PID file is incorrectly determined to be `2>&1.pid` as evidenced by your error.

The line of code as shown here will still hang indefinitely if the ZNC program does not daemonise itself and fork into the background. I don't have ZNC so I cannot test this part, but given that the CentOS daemon utility offers no option to background a task I should hope that this basic requirement has been addressed within ZNC itself.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already created a new user account

```
sudo useradd --system --shell /sbin/nologin --comment "Account to run ZNC daemon" --user-group znc
```

And you've already made a config file:

Your init.d script on CentOS should look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# znc - Advanced IRC Bouncer INIT script #
# description: An Advanced IRC bouncer INIT script for
# Source function library.
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

exec=/usr/bin/znc
prog=znc
config=/var/lib/znc
runas=znc

lockfile=/var/lock/subsys/$prog

start() {
    [ -x $exec ] || exit 5
    echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
    # if not running, start it up here, usually something like "daemon $exec"
    daemon --user $runas "$exec -d $config >/dev/null 2>&1"
    # If you're reckless with your system, comment the line above and
    # uncomment this one below... I just don't get it why
    # daemon "$exec -r -d $config >/dev/null 2>&1"
    retval=$?
    echo
    [ $retval -eq 0 ] && touch $lockfile
    return $retval
}

stop() {
    echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
    # stop it here, often "killproc $prog"
    killproc $prog -TERM
    retval=$?
    echo
    [ $retval -eq 0 ] && rm -f $lockfile
    return $retval
}

reload() {
    echo -n $"Reloading $prog: "
    # stop it here, often "killproc $prog"
    killproc $prog -HUP
    retval=$?
    echo
}

restart() {
    stop
    start
}

rh_status() {
    # run checks to determine if the service is running or use generic status
    status $prog
}

rh_status_q() {
    rh_status >/dev/null 2>&1
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        rh_status_q && exit 0
        $1
        ;;
    stop)
        rh_status_q || exit 0
        $1
        ;;
    restart)
        $1
        ;;
    reload)
        rh_status_q || exit 7
        $1
        ;;
    status)
        rh_status
        ;;
    condrestart|try-restart)
        rh_status_q || exit 0
        restart
        ;;
    *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|reload|restart|condrestart|try-restart}"
        exit 2
esac
exit $?
```

Make sure to `chmod +x` it otherwise you could use crontab simply adding

```
*/10 * * * *   /usr/bin/znc >/dev/null 2>&1
```

to your crontab (`crontab -e`)

Replacing 10 to a lower value for a more agressive checking

Answer (score 0):

`daemon --user $runas --check $exec "$exec -d $config >/dev/null 2>&1"`. I've just added `--check $exec`. The daemon function couldn't get `znc` from `"$exec -d $config >/dev/null 2>&1"`to make up a pid file as `/var/run/znc.pid`, insted it gets `${1##*/}` this evaluates to 'null 2>&1'.The `--check $exec` ensures it gets it right.
Or you can pass `pidfile=/var/run/$(basename $exec).pid daemon --user $runas --pidfile $pidfile "$exec -d $config >/dev/null 2>&1"`

If the whole thing is not quoted like "$exec -d $config >/dev/null 2>&1", the 'daemon' function's stdout and stderr are redirected and any output message or errors from 'daemon' function will not show up during start. It should shout when it needs to. It shouldn't be shut up. When quoted, it's passed as '$*' to the daemon function so that $exec's stdout and stderr are correctly redirected. Quoting $exec alone doesn't do anything unless it has white space in its name or path.

System daemons don't have to be redirected to /dev/null, because they close all open FDs and open /dev/null on 0,1 and 2 themselves and detach from terminal and use logs for output. Here I think the 'znc' needs I/O redir because it doesn't do the redir itself.

Comment: Since $exec's stdin/stdout are inherited from daemon, redirecting daemon's stdin/stdout implicitly affects $exec too.

Comment: If stdout and stderr of daemon function get redirected to /dev/null, we won't get any messages from this function or any functions called from within. It's better to redirect stdout and stderr of $exec only here.