# Unable to start ZNC as a service

Tags: shell-script, centos, services, init-script, init.d

Firstly, this is the exact same question as found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170613/cant-start-a-znc-service), but the given solutions did not work in my situation.

### Background

I am running a CentOS 6 VPS and I want to run a ZNC bouncer on it. I configured the service initially through `sudo -u znc znc --makeconf` and did not run into issues. I was successfully able to start it.

### Problem

However, I went to restart ZNC and immediately ran into issues when trying to reboot.

```
# service znc start
Starting znc: /usr/bin/dirname: extra operand `2>&1.pid'
Try `/usr/bin/dirname --help' for more information.
                                                           [FAILED]
```

I began looking through my initscript for ZNC and like others had pointed in other sources online, there appears to be an issue with the placement of an apostrophe.

```
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

exec=/usr/bin/znc
prog=znc
config=/var/lib/znc
runas=znc

lockfile=/var/lock/subsys/$prog

start() {
[ -x $exec ] || exit 5
echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
daemon --user $runas "$exec -d $config >/dev/null 2>&1"
# daemon --user $runas --check $exec "$exec -d $config >/dev/null 2>&1"
retval=$?
echo
[ $retval -eq 0 ] && touch $lockfile
return $retval
}
```

### Attempted Fix

The `daemon` line in the `start()` method appears to be the issue. I tried modifying it to the following:

```
daemon --user $runas "$exec" -d $config >/dev/null 2>&1
```

However, modifying it to this does fix the error, but when I go to start ZNC with `service znc start`, I just get a blank output - neither `[OK]` or `[FAILED]` are given. The service ultimately does not start and this is verified by `service znc status`.

I am confused about the issue and not sure how to proceed in figuring out the cause of the issue. Further troubleshooting advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by editing the offending line in `/etc/rc.d/init.d/znc` from:

```
daemon --user $runas "$exec -d $config >/dev/null 2>&1"
```

to the following:

```
daemon --user $runas "$exec -d $config >/dev/null"
```

(i.e., Remove the stderr redirect, 2>&1)

This now gives me confirmation that the service started OK or that it failed:

```
root@localhost [~]# service znc restart
Stopping znc:                                              [FAILED]
Starting znc:                                              [  OK  ]
```

In addition, at least on my yum installation (CentOS 6.7), I also had to modify this line in the same file to point to the correct configuration directory (line 12):

```
config=/var/lib/znc
```

to:

```
config=/var/lib/znc/.znc
```

Prior to this, znc would fail to start because it couldn't find the configuration file that I had previously generated with `sudo -H -u znc znc --makeconf`.